# Integrating the Google Cloud Platform API into a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, api-design

I am creating a basic flask app that outputs a list of instances running on a GCP project into the browser but I'm coming across some issues when returning the result of the api call inside the browser.

My flask app looks something like this:

```
@app.route(API_ROOT + 'list')
def list_all_running():
    return test_list.list_all_running_instances()
```

and the function I'm trying to return looks like this

```
def list_all_running_instances():

    request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone='europe-west1-d')
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        for instance in response['items']:
            # if instance['status'] == 'RUNNING':
            return instance
        request = service.instances().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

This is a shortened and adapted version of [this script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list) listed under 'python' in the examples at the bottom of the page.

The issue is when I call the function in flask it only returns the first instance running. In the original gcp api script example it uses `pprint` rather than return, which works fine on the console but I am unable to output the `pprint` results to a browser.

Can anyone recommend the best way of doing this? Is there a way you can output `pprint` into the browser via Flask. I realise that when returning it will only output the result of the first iteration and then stop, hence this issue.

As you can tell I'm quite new at Flask, so apologies if this seems like a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `return` statement which finishes execution of your `list_all_running_instances` function. You can do something like this:

```
def list_all_running_instances():

    request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone='europe-west1-d')
    all_instances = []
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        all_instances.extend(response['items'])
        request = service.instances().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
    return {'all_instances': all_instances}
```

Comment: Great stuff, seems to do what I need it to do. Thanks!